# Can't call System.Web.Services.WebMethod

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, pagemethods

**Disclaimer**: *I feel like I ask that question everytime when I try to use it, maybe one day I'll understand why it even works sometimes*

I've got in codebehind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void foo() {
    anotherstaticclass.myval = false;
}
```

On `aspx` :

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" >
```

and on client check-box switch I've got function with `PageMethods.foo();`

```
function foo() {
    var loc = window.location.href;
    loc = (loc.substr(loc.length - 1, 1) == "/") ? loc + "Default.aspx" : loc;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: loc + "/foo",
        data: '{ }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg.d)
        }
    });
}
```

But seems like method is not being called on check. Value is not changed and just nothing happens. What else should I do?

Comment: How do you check the value of the myval?

Comment: @VMAtm I check it later on another call, it's static.

Comment: It's static field of the class that being re-created for each new request. Web pages are stateless, they don't store their data anythere. Try to debug your static constructor for this class.

Comment: @VMAtm not sure about it... But moving this value to another class also not helped.

Comment: Could you also post your code where you actually call the page method from AJAX?

Comment: Try to add `[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]` and store value in the session. WebServices are not supposed to store some data into themselves.

Comment: Your method is void, and you are trying to get return value. May be you should change signature of your `WebMethod`?

Comment: @VMAtm Yes... I had tried a lot! when I set return type to `string` and `return "OK"` nothing changes. (If I just `return "OK";` without changing another value I've got same effect)

Comment: Some things to try: 
-Change to "GET" rather than POST (just to see)
-remove `contentType` and `dataType`

Also, create an error handler to see if the error tells you anything

Comment: I think you have to use **[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]**
 and **foo() method should not be static**